# Is Heroku rewrites Spring Boot's spring.datasource.url, spring.datasource.username and spring.datasource.password properties?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, heroku

I have spring boot app (https://github.com/trip2gafa/street-art) with JDBC configured in it.

In application.yml file, I have these configurations:

```
datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/street-art-db
    username: street-art
    password: street-art
```

*Application.yml file: https://github.com/trip2gafa/street-art/blob/master/src/main/resources/application.yml*

But, database credentials in Heroku differs from credentials that I show in my application.yml file. 
Does it mean that Heroku  just rewrites `spring.datasource.url`, `spring.datasource.username` and `spring.datasource.password` properties?

Answer (score 1):

In this [link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-spring-boot-apps-to-heroku) it's described how to configure DB in heroku.
[image]

---

[image]

Hope this answer will help you homie, don't be scared homie (c) Nick Diaz